Can I make GRUB Loader to load the opposite operative system / disk (of the last used) on boot?
Currently in my settings I have GRUB_DEFAULT=saved, this means that whenever I reboot, I get the same disk / operative system that I was at.
For context, I have a disk with Ubuntu and another disk with Windows 10.
I wanted to know whether it's possible to reboot and choose the opposite disk of the one I last used.
For example, right now I'm using the Ubuntu disk. If I reboot, I want it to automatically choose Windows 10. If I reboot on Windows 10, I want it to automatically choose Ubuntu.
Is this possible? I could only find for specific indexes or titles or last used, but not the opposite of last used.
